# Extremely simple app and a text file, best way to distribute on Windows Store?

Tags: wpf, uwp, windows-store-apps, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

I have an *extremely* simple application I'd like to distribute on the Windows Store. This is the first I've looked at Store.

The entire project consists of the exe and readme.txt. The app has a button that opens a second window and displays the contents of the readme.

The exe will be packaged using Desktop App Converter (DAP). Is there a way I can add the text file to the package as part of the DAP process or post-process?

I know I can put the file inside the exe as a resource, but I'd like to avoid doing that simply so the user can open it in their own text editor as well.

Comment: There is not much point to that, the user will never find that text file.  Anything you deploy through an appx package is deeply buried in a hidden subdirectory.  Feature, not a bug.

Comment: Ahh, so the .exe is not really visible either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can add the text file to the package as part of the DAP process or post-process?

You could firstly use DAC tool to convert your WPF application. Then you could modify the packaged app by adding the text file into visual assets folder:

[image]

Then you need to manually [generate a new Package Resource Index file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion#make-pri) and repackage your app using MakeAppx tool.

You could open your command tool and Change directory to the package's root folder, and then create a priconfig.xml file:

`makepri createconfig /cf priconfig.xml /dq en-US`

Create the resources.pri file(s) by using the command

`makepri new /pr <PHYSICAL_PATH_TO_FOLDER> /cf <PHYSICAL_PATH_TO_FOLDER>\priconfig.xml`

For example: `makepri new /pr c:\MYAPP /cf c:\MYAPP\priconfig.xml`

Finally, you need to generate a new package:

`makeappx pack -d "C:\VLCUWP\VLCUWPApp\VLCUWPApp\PackageFiles" -p "C:\VLCUWP\VLCUWPApp\VLCUWPApp\VLCUWPApp.appx"`.

For more details, please refer to [Create an app package with the MakeAppx.exe tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/create-app-package-with-makeappx-tool).

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio 2017 **Update 4**, this has become much easier now. You don't have to use the Desktop App Converter for projects like this anymore, you can do the packaging directly and easily in VS with the new Packaging Project type. You can just add that to your WPF source project and it will take care of packing the EXE and the text file and whatever else you want to package into the .appx package.

Here is a blog post explaining the details:
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/10/18/visual-studio-2017-update-4-makes-easy-modernize-desktop-application-make-store-ready/

Comment: I will take a look. I am currently on 2015 but there's no particular reason for that.